# No screws at the front of my Bit Fenix Comrade Case for fan

Tags: fan, case

I am using the BitFenix Comrade which does feature slots in the front for fans but when trying to install a fan there I found out that there are no screw holes for a fan even though there is a dust collector for 2 possible fans. Does anyone know how I am supposed to install a fan into my BitFenix Comrade case?

Case:

[image: BitFenix Comrade]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing the plastic insert (aka "The Front Dust Filter") the fans mount to:

[image: front of chassis with filter installed]

Go back to whomever supplied the chassis and ask them for the part. Otherwise, contact [BenFenix's support](https://support.bitfenix.com/) directly to locate a source for the part.

Comment: After further inspection I found out that the fan screws into that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after researching I found a review here:

http://www.pcgameware.co.uk/reviews/cases/bitfenix-comrade-case-review/

That appears to say the fans mount to the dust filter:

> More interestingly this also shows a removable air filter with mounts for two optional 120mm fans.

and a picture:

http://www.pcgameware.co.uk/images/BitFenix-Comrade-Front-Panel-Removed.jpg

If that's not the answer then I don't know where they go.